# In Leaflet, how to load tiles only when clicking on each?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a leaflet map consisting of a satellite image with lat-long metadata. My objective is to display a rectangle highlighting the selected tile on mouseclick and fetch the corresponding tile. The L.rectangle method needs bounds to display the rectangle. In order to calculate the SE and NW corners, I use the following function that I found at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Tile_numbers_to_lon..2Flat.

This is for SE and the same function is changed for getting NW as seen in the above link. These are used as bounds for the rectangle.

```
//I have a fixed zoom level for my problem :4

function(xtile,ytile,zoom) //here i am giving the tile location coordinates as the input
{ 
n=2.0**zoom;
lon= (xtile+1)/n*360-180;
lat_rad=Math.atan(Math.Sinh(Math.PI*(1-2*(ytile+1)/n)));
lat=lat_rad(180/Math.PI);
return[-lat,lon] 
}
```

The output comes out to be as follows:

```
NW -782.67,-112.4
SE -79.163,-89.9
with(suppose) xtile=5 and ytile=14
```

The actual output however should have been:

```
NW -66.51,-45
SE -74.01,-22.5
and the corresponding(again,suppose) xtile=5 and ytile=1
```

So basically, for some tiles , the rectangle shows just fine. But for others, it jumps to some other tile. I have a display window for the selected tileand when the rectangle jumps, neither the selected tile nor the highlighted tile is fetched. I will be really thankful is someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My objective is to display a rectangle highlighting the selected tile on mouseclick and fetch the corresponding tile.

Then a good approach to the root problem is to use a custom `L.GridLayer`, since it provides functionality to create empty tiles, attach events to them and handle tile coordinates without the need to handle bounding boxes explicitly.

It would go like this:

```
L.GridLayer.ClickyLoad = L.GridLayer.extend({

  // By default, the container for a whole zoom level worth of visible tiles
  // has a "pointer-events: none" CSS property. Override this whenever a new
  // level container is created. This is needed for pointer (mouse) interaction.
  _onCreateLevel: function(level) {
    level.el.style.pointerEvents = 'inherit';
  },

  // The tiles shall be empty <div>s with some DOM events attached.
  createTile: function(coords){

        var tile = L.DomUtil.create('div');

    tile.style.border = '1px solid black';

    // Highlighting the tile on mouse hover is just swag.    
    L.DomEvent.on(tile, 'mouseover', function(){
      tile.style.border = '2px solid red';
    });
    L.DomEvent.on(tile, 'mouseout', function(){
      tile.style.border = '1px solid black';
    });

    // When a tile is clicked, calculate the URL of the tile (using the same 
    // logic as L.TileLayer.getTileUrl() ), create a <img> element, and put
    // the newly created image inside the empty <div> tile.
    L.DomEvent.on(tile, 'click', function(){
      var img = L.DomUtil.create('img');
      img.src = L.Util.template('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', coords);
      tile.appendChild(img);
    });

    return tile;
  }
});

// Create instance and add to map
(new L.GridLayer.ClickyLoad()).addTo(map);
```

See a [fully working example here](https://plnkr.co/edit/0BxzmEEixhRTG16AvDLo?p=preview).

As usual with this kind of non-trivial-looking examples, reading through the [Leaflet documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference), the [tutorial about extending classes](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-2-layers.html), and the Leaflet source code itself is recommended.

Comment: Thank for this solution. It is working for me,however there is a small problem that arises in your demo and hence my code as well. When we click on any tile, the tile image gets appended vertically. For example, if I click on a tile three times, the tile image is displayed thrice vertically downwards. Kindly cross check if this is indeed happenning or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: Yeah, the code is not checking for that. You should add a flag to cover that case.